# Detection changes in Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

Is it possible to detect file uploading/deleting in File Storage(not Blob Storage) and call some custom handler after that

Comment: Can you specify your question more clearly?

Comment: for example if new file is uploaded in file storage(by any method: by Azure portal interface or Azure Storage Explorer, programmatically by my code) I want to call some web API method which save name and path of this file in my database

Comment: Hi,John. I'm afraid you cannot achieve this directly. All APIs for Azure File Storage cannot reach your requirement. But, You can get the lthe lists files and directories within the share or specified directory. What I think is that you can request API frequently, and you could write code to compare with the difference between two API requests.Then send the information to you database. It's just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Wayne Yang -MSFT mentioned that azure file trigger is **not supported** by Azure currently. But Azure team is planning for it, deails you could refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/17561860-should-support-trigger-for-azure-files).

If Azure blob storage is possible, you could use the azure [event grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview) to detect to the blob changes and trigger the Webhook with the function to save name and path of this file in my database.